# How do I scan a SD Memory Stick from my Phone and recover accidently deleted photos?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I used the Android "Gallery" app and accidentally deleted all my photos.

Can I plug my memory stick into Ubuntu, and DD recover the disk, and somehow recover the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Photorec to recover the images. Run with no arguments and follow instructions, it should guide you step by step

```
sudo photorec
```

I would suggest following the guide here   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Imaging_a_damaged_device.2C_filesystem_or_drive to image the card before just in case

EDIT:
Also before you go through the trouble try plugging the sd card into the computer and checking through all the folders (look at hidden too) I seem to remember a trash folder, Android might have put them there

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I am going to try this now!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: cool let me know how it goes

Comment: Waiting for parent to replug the usb so I can try it, sorry its taking a while will let you know how it goes. For now my battle plan is: (Parent computer is Windows so: 1. install vbox 2. map the usb stick of the droid to vbox 3. boot up ubuntu live cd, and dd from the stick to a flat file 4. photorec or testdisk on the flat file to try and recover the files!)